# Javascript background URL image NOT showing up on Safari browser

Tags: javascript, css, safari, liquid

Im trying to display a products image in Javascript, like this:

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

        var image,caption;

        function sectionHtml(caption,image){
          return '<div class="mason-image" style="background: url('+image+') center center; background-size: cover;"><h3>'+ caption +'</h3></div>';
        }

        caption = $($('.image-bar__item')[0]).text()
        image = $($('.image-bar__item.image-bar__link')[0]).css('background-image').replace('url("','').replace('")','')


// More stuff here, not related to image
 });
</script>
```

The image shows up great on chrome, and Internet Explorer, but on Safari, the image does not show up.

Here is how the inspected code looks on Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

This is what shows up on Safari Developer console:

[image]

The "url" part shows up twice on safari, thats why its breaking. Is there a way I can fix that so it does not show up twice on Safari?

Comment: This works for me in safari http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxXzOy?editors=1010. Can you give us a working demo please?

Comment: I cant give you the url because this is a clients website, and its password protected right now. Nobody can access it besides the client and developer.

Comment: I'm not asking for you to link us to a 3rd party site. I'm asking you to reproduce the problem in the post on SO with the minimum amount of code to replicate the issue. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."*

Comment: Try putting ' around your url: `style="background: url('htps://...') center center;` Maybe that helps.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I had to do to get it working:

```
'<div class="mason-image" style="background: url(' + image + ') center center;"></div>';

image = $($('.image-bar__item.image-bar__link')[0]).css('background-image').replace('url','').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace('"','').replace('"','')
```